# Typescript type for two types with same keys and similar values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a class that take an object as a constructor argument, and I want to enforce a method on the class to accept a very similar object.  The objects have arbitrary keys.

For example, constructing with this object:

```js
{
  foo: { type: 'A' },
  bar: { type: 'B'}
}
```

I will want the method to only accept objects of a similar form, i.e. has the same keys and for each key the value type is compatible with the initial object.  like:

```js
{
  foo: SomeARelatedThing,
  bar: SomeBRelatedThing
}
```

I've got a workaround in place where I can at least enforce the same keys, and then do lots of type checking (good to do anyway!) to make sure that the values actually match up.

Here's a contrived example from my use case:

```js
type TypeName = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' // ...

class Action<K extends TypeName> { 
  type: K
  constructor(type: K) { this.type = type } 
}
type AnyAction = Action<'A'> | Action<'B'> | Action<'C'> // ...

type AProp = { type: 'A' }
type BProp = { type: 'B' }
type CProp = { type: 'C' }
type AnyProp = AProp | BProp | CProp // ...

type PropMap<K extends string> = Record<K, AnyProp>
type ActionMap<K extends string> = Record<K, AnyAction>

class Thing<K extends string> {
  props: PropMap<K>
  constructor(props: PropMap<K>) { this.props = props }

  myMethod<>(actions: ActionMap<K>) { /* ... */ }
}

// type = Thing<'foo' | 'bar'>
const thing = new Thing({
  foo: { type: 'A' },
  bar: { type: 'B'}
})

// the keys are enforced, but how can the values of foo and bar be enforced, too
thing.myMethod({
  foo: new Action('A'),
  bar: new Action('B'),
})
```

I think I would want something more like a type equal to `Thing<{foo: 'A', bar: 'B'}>`, but I don't know how to conditionally compute that from a `PropMap`-like input to the `Thing` constructor, or even if I did, then how would I compute the correct `ActionMap`-like type.

`MyMethod` actually accepts a `Partial<ActionMap<K>>` but I don't *think* that that should matter for what I am asking.

Comment: Why would you work with objects with abitrary keys? The whole point of TypeScript is that you can do static type analysis before any code even runs, "arbitrary keys" is the antithesis of that.

Comment: What do you mean "the keys are enforced, but how can the values of foo and bar be enforced, too"? Do you mean that if you create an instance of `Thing` with `foo: {type: 'A'}` that the string literal `'A'` must match there and in `myMethod({foo: new Action('A')})`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans there is more to TypeScript than just "objects with strictly defined keys". This is a perfectly valid use case. :)

Comment: There is, but also question deviations from the absolute basics. There might be a usecase, but "I need arbitrary keys" 99% of the time is someone unwilling to give up JS's freedom, so let's make sure that's not the case here =)

Comment: The attempt here is to create something like a special kind of "interface" within a framework.  A library of what I called class "Thing" here can be defined, and a variety of applications can provide different implementations for each of them.  The framework doesn't care what the keys will be, and a user should only care about the form of the implementation, the "Actions" noted here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you're right in the sense that if I were only working in a single app then I would just create the types for the single purpose, but I'm working more on a library framework.  Types are indeed the point of Typescript.  The magic (that Jered helped with) will make the types be useful to end users of the framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it. You need to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
class Thing<K extends string, P extends PropMap<K>> {
  props: P
  constructor(props: P) { this.props = props }

  myMethod(actions: {[Property in keyof P]: Action<P[Property]["type"]>}) { return actions }
}

const thing = new Thing({
  foo: { type: 'A' },
  bar: { type: 'B'}
})

// the keys are enforced, as well as the corresponding Action types
thing.myMethod({
  foo: new Action('A'),
  bar: new Action('B'),
})
```

Note that you need to add the generic `P` to your `Thing` class, otherwise TypeScript has no way of inferring more detailed information when you instantiate `Thing` later. Basically, you need to set `P` to be the same generic type consistently *within* `Thing` otherwise there is no way to differentiate it from the type `PropMap` which it extends.

Then, the magic happens in `actions: {[Property in keyof P]: Action<P[Property]["type"]>}`. Let's break it down:

1. `[Property in keyof P]:` mapped type index signature. This is what lets us get access to the specific keys in `P`, e.g. `foo`, `bar` etc.
2. `Action<...>` will set the value corresponding to each key we're mapping in (1.) above to some value, which we want to be an `Action`, like `Action<'A'>` etc. *BUT* we want the action to be derived from the *original* value of `P`, so...
3. `P[Property]["type"]` let's us access the value from the `type` key/value pair from the original type of `P`. Since `Property` varies (it's mapped from one type to the other) then for example it becomes `foo: P["foo"]["type"]` which is `'A'`, `bar: P["bar"]["type"]` which is `'B'`, etc

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEDkCGBbaBeKByAglqAPtgEL5FYDC%20A9NVAHSMBQTAxgDZIDOXUOrwAJYB7AHYAeANJQIAD2ARRAE15xIyNAD4oAbyhMoUUJABcUSQaisxXYACcArgOF2AFMYhnJASl1GAFoJc9B5QmKEAvvoRTKE4oiD8QmJhfAIiErhY2kRJGeJYpDlpyZlU2rQMzLHwfAAKdsJgqXoeZllQMaHEDU0tRvDtpJ01kFAUvc2YrYPYVCNxCZOpOMtEPY3NRBObUJWM9CyhkwCySGBSMvKKKlC2doKiAObamABKENZ2SlIANHxLTaaUbQPJiM4XaRyBTKXj3R4vVIfL4-ST-eKJdJiYEgkoZCEAJku0JucPsCP%20AHlXlBkS5UVScaFKWBSlwAGKcJ5ccRqCA0nSWADakwgdlAUEeUAA1hAQMIAGaweAAXTMAG4mBFNWxODxYIFnsTrrC7uTnv86lcYbdTucpJptILDGBNlwzHVLNZRPcnMAXK5XU13VA6r5WoFgkGwLxMNHeDFLCgQCcIMB-MIlK4kFifWYdCLNmKJVLZfKlXU1XixOI6oWmsWQCqhQAiDwtlWaCLhqB2NMOOyiKA5tkjROVUKYGCGp4FBXCYRkbAAIyQdmybBswACCNSoggAHcDQjXM6oPPhPmBqZsHhOr9LKu7Fe2iQsDFuywJ-5oGXeGvoEUec7FYCAlH%20ZcHG3DMj1YJAh3TaAADckHYBwIF4RVzwXYdlCgJ98MA0RgNA8CjAXWIZ3oZNU3TTNT0sC8zH3I8wVEVwsm8B9DCfZjD2rdjCiwLitV8L86APRpnmHXNr2gJ5BCQjCoAcXgxUaOwuEohFqJTNMMyzM8mKgFiBI40gRJ4tc%20NY3NzOEh9uygIA)

[image]

Comment: This also allows me to make `PropMap` concrete and not generic and `Thing` shouldn't need the `K` anymore.  Cool! Also, `ActionMap` could be defined generic like `ActionMap<P extends PropMap> = {[Property in keyof P]: Action<P[Property]["type"]>}`